# Swift: Getting currency symbol from an amount text

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsnumberformatter

How can I extract **currency symbol** from strings which contain both amount and symbols. These strings can be in any international formats as I'm getting them from `NumberFormatter`. Some examples of such strings and their results are as follows:-

$446.99 =-> $

US$445,34 45 => US$

445,34 45 US$ => US$

THB567 => THB

567 THB => THB

and many more.

I already know about `NumberFormatter` properties `currencySymbol`, `internationalCurrencySymbol` but they don't help in getting to a universal solution as in case of US$ they return you $ and USD respectively. If there is any `regex` out there then I'm happy to try that too.

PS: I need this information to format my currency symbols according to following pic:-
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the methods which `filter out` the mention characters from a `String`:

```
let filteredString = String("567 THB".filter { String($0).rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.,")) == nil }).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
//TBH <- prints
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do as below:

```
let currency = str.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789., "))
```